# Regression model comparison/validation in an independent cohort: other method than c-index

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, roc, validation, model-comparison

**What I have:**

I developed a logistic regression model (M1) to predict lymph node metastasis in cancer patients using the variables A + B + C + D + E and a training/validation data set D1, E is the new measurement of interest.

M2 is (among others) a published prediction tool (i.e. a logistic regression model using variables A + B + C + D + F with published coefficients -> Lymph Node Involvement (Cores), https://www.mskcc.org/nomograms/prostate/pre_op/coefficients).

**What I would like to do:**

To compare M1 to M2 regarding their performance using an external data set (D2). I would like to investigate, if M1 is comparable or even more accurate than M2 in predicting lymph node metastasis.

**My thoughts:**

I thought about to predict the probabilities with M1 and M2 in D2 and compare them by using the c-index, however, I've learned that this is a low power procedure (https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/). However, this technique is often used to compare prediction tools in this field (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28644701/). The same source states that comparing the Models with a likelihood ratio (LR) test could be a better approach.

**My questions:**

1. How can I compare M1 to M2 using a LR test? *([How to do external validation of regression models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66457/how-to-do-external-validation-of-regression-models) Q2 is similar to my question, however I do not fully understand how to proceed, a step-by-step approach would of high interest.)*
2. I am also not sure of the LR approach would be of use for my purpose *(as I understand I had to "reconstruct" M2 with the published data and D2 which leads to another regression formula which would yield different results as the original forumla of M2 that clinicians use, e.g. by an online calculator https://www.mskcc.org/nomograms/prostate/pre_op))*
3. Is there another method to compare my model to the published model for my puropse? *(e.g. H-measure, IDI, NRI)*